# MYSQL split date range columns into dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table [T] with columns `id`,`start_date`, `end_date`. I want to get `id`, `date`, where id is split into multiple dates using start date and end date.
For example:
Input:

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-03 | 2022-04-07 |
| 2 | 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-11 |

Expected Output

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-03 |
| 1 | 2022-04-04 |
| 1 | 2022-04-05 |
| 1 | 2022-04-06 |
| 1 | 2022-04-07 |
| 2 | 2022-04-11 |

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: The version is MySQL 8

Comment: You can use a recursive Common Table expression to create a domain of dates. Use min(start_date) as the base case for the recursion och increment until max(end_date). Then join this with your table using the between predicate

Answer (score 0):

Build a `dates` table with all possible dates.

```
INSERT INTO OutputTable (t_id, date)
    SELECT T.id, d.date
        FROM T
        JOIN dates AS d
        WHERE d.date BETWEEN T.start_date AND T.end_date;
```

(By convention `id` is assumed to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence unique, for a table.  So, I changed to `t_id` for your output.)